# React Native rendering a component

Tags: react-native, rendering, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList that renders an Item

```
<FlatList
        data={this.state.color}
        renderItem={this.displayColor}
        horizontal={true}
        keyExtractor={item => item.color}
    />
```

displayColor

```
displayColor= ({ item }) => {
    let btncolor = 'white'
    if(item.color == this.state.fcolor){
        btncolor = 'red'
    }
    return(
        <Color color={item.color} btncolor ={btncolor} colorChosen ={() =>this.chooseColor(item)}/>
   )         
}
```

chooseColor

```
chooseColor(item){
   this.setState({
       fcolor:item.color
   })
  this.displayColor({item}) // NOT WORKING
}
```

My Task is to show the current selected Button in the Color component with red colour, the above code is getting the work done but it needs to render the func displayColor so it will check the state with item.color after the chooseColor func setstate fcolor, but I couldn't call the displayColor func to refresh in chooseColor func, how can I do that or there is a simple way to get the task done. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an extraData prop to your FlatList

```
<FlatList
        data={this.state.color}
        renderItem={this.displayColor}
        horizontal={true}
        extraData={this.state.fcolor} //Add this line to your FlatList
        keyExtractor={item => item.color}
    />
```